# SMTP configuration

Tags: php, smtp

I have the Vista Home Premium operating system and I am developing an PHP web application
that sends out emails.

I need to configure SMTP and I have tried several options from installing
PHPmailer. btu the sad thing is it did not send an email.

Should I continue to try to figure out PHPmailer or is there a better way?
If PHPmailer is the way to go, how do I go about configuring this?

Comment: Where are you going to send those mails? You will have to configure a SMTP server that you can authenticate to.

Comment: You didn't like the answers that you got to your very similar question, I guess. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634029/how-to-send-mail-using-php

Comment: And that other even more similar question? Those answers weren't your cup of tea either? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612277/how-can-i-configure-the-mail-function-of-php-on-windows-vista

Answer (score 3):

An SMTP Server is not included with Vista.

http://weblogs.asp.net/steveschofield/archive/2006/12/19/iis7-post-23-vista-and-smtp-server-where-is-it.aspx