# phpmailer, requre() and include_path combined

Tags: ssl, openssl, phpmailer

After 5 long day trying to set up sending e-mail from php script, I finaly did it from my local server, i use apache.

From the host, i can't do it. 
I get this error->

SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host

So, I've searched around stack overflow, among others. I tried using SMTPSecure = 'ssl', did nothing. I checked is extension=php_openssl.dll commented out, but it doesn't even exist on my host. I mean, there is no file in php.ini named php_openssl.dll. There is only information that Openssl is installed under Curl section and what version is it. Under openssl section says that it is enabled. The same configuration is on my computer and on the host but mails wont be sent on host.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: What server do you have (linux or Windows)? How are config lines, related to smtp, set in php.ini? How are you sending mail (using mail() function or using some extension? How is openssl related to the question at all?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, but the question wasn't well explained. I use XAMPP on Windows. I have successfully sent an email from local server on my computer but couldn't do it on the host. I thought it was ssl beacuse, before i got the error mentioned above, i got an error that my username or password of the gmail account were incorrect. So i put SMTPSecure = 'ssl' and the error was gone, but then there was the error above.

Comment: I am not sure if PHP engine can send mail via GMail as SMTP at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your host setup will be different to your local server, so you'll need a different configuration. It would seem your host has installed an email server. Unless you have set one up on your local machine, your PHP script, when using the same settings, will fail. Also, your host will probably have restrictions on it's email server, meaning you probably can't use it to send emails from your local server. (You should ask them). The alternative is outlined in this post:

[How can I configure the mail function of PHP on Windows Vista?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612277/how-can-i-configure-the-mail-function-of-php-on-windows-vista)

If you are having trouble sending mail on your host, you should ask them for the details of how to connect to the email server. It is quite possible they restrict the use to stop spam mails being sent.

Comment: i failed to mention that I'm a beginner of php and this is my first time making scripts that send mails.